# Is dd able to overwrite parts of a file?

Tags: dd

I have a 1TB big file (disk-image from a damaged drive) and a 1.3MB small file (beginning of a disk-file).

Using the contents of the small file, I want to overwrite portions of the big file. That is, I want to insert/overwrite the first 1.3MB of the 1TB-image using the small file.

Using small temporary files for testing I was unable to overwrite parts of the files. Rather, dd overwrote the files completely. This is not what I want.

Is dd able to do this?

Comment: In addition to the very good answers below, you can use the `seek=nn` and `skip=nn` parameters to set the starting points in your files, and `count=nn` to copy less than the whole input file.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you use the `conv=notrunc` argument, you can replace just the first however many bytes.
e.g.  `dd conv=notrunc if=small.img of=large.img`

```
root@debian:~/ddtest# dd if=/dev/zero of=file1.img bs=1M count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 1.14556 s, 9.2 MB/s
root@debian:~/ddtest# dd if=/dev/urandom of=file2.img bs=1M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.207185 s, 5.1 MB/s
root@debian:~/ddtest# head file1.img 

<< Blank space here as it's all Zeroes >>

root@debian:~/ddtest# dd conv=notrunc if=file2.img of=file1.img 
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00468016 s, 224 MB/s
root@debian:~/ddtest# head file1.img 
^�v�y�ے!� E�91����  << SNIP Random garbage >>
root@debian:~/ddtest#
```

Comment: And it wasn't part of the original question, but you can write to somewhere other than the beginning of the output file using the `seek` option, and start reading somewhere other than the beginning of the input file using the `skip` option. Together with the other options, you can copy an arbitrary part of one file to an arbitrary position in another.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to overwrite only at the start of the file, and leave the rest intact, use the [`conv=notrunc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html#tag_20_31_05) option to prevent truncation:

```
dd conv=notrunc if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024 count=1024
```

`notrunc` [means](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html#tag_20_31_05):

> Do not truncate the output file. Preserve blocks in the output file not explicitly written by this invocation of the *dd* utility.

It is in POSIX and so supported by every version of `dd`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to overwrite the **start** of `big-file` with the content of `small-file` without affecting the rest, you can just do with any Bourne-like shell:

```
cat small-file 1<> big-file
```

The `<>` redirection operator opens the file in read+write mode without truncation. That would be equivalent to using `dd`'s `conv=notrunc` but without all the problems and limitations of `dd`.

If you want to write the content anywhere else than at the very start of the file, you'd need to seek at the desired position in the file. That's where `dd` and its `seek=xxx` comes handy, though you could also use a shell that has builtin seek operators like `ksh93` or `zsh`:

```
cat small-file 1<> big-file >#((12345)) # ksh93

zmodload zsh/system; {sysseek -u1 12345 && cat small-file} 1<> big-file # zsh
```

Comment: ```but without all the problems and limitations of dd``` what problems and limitations?

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
printf '\xa1' | dd conv=notrunc of=Yourfile bs=1 seek=$((0xoffset))
```